# Does jQuery always return array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

Does jQuery always return array when selecting element (of course if at least one element exists)? Example:

```
$('#Myelement')
$('div')
$('tbody')
```

What if the selector is an ID?
What if the selector is an element but has only one occurrence?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The jQuery function always returns a [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object (that is based on an array), even if there are no elements that matches the selector.

That way you can always call a method that is supposed to affect the elements found, even if there are no elements that matched. If the jQuery object contains no elements, it will simply do nothing.

If you need to know if a jQuery object contains any elements, you can use the `length` property.

Comment: In my opinion, your second statement isn't a good explanation, because this isn't why jQuery returns an array. It's because $() finds elements matching a given selector, so you can't expect the element having some id, but a result containing the element having some id.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer: The second paragraph is not an explanation of why the methods returns an array, it's an explanation of how you can use that to your advantage. I'm afraid that I don't understand what you mean with the explanation that you offer.

Comment: But when I do `$('td')[0].html('hi')`, it gives me an exception, it says that index has no `.html` method, meaning the elements on the array returned by jQuery are not part of the jQuery object. Am I wrong?

Comment: @domanokz: The jQuery object contains elements, it doesn't contain jQuery objects. If you use `[0]` to get an element out of the jQUery object, it's a plain DOM element that you can't use jQuery methods on. You can use the `first` method to limit the result to the first element: `$('td').first().html('hi')`, or you can wrap the element in a jQuery object: `$($('td')[0]).html('hi')` (but that will cause an error if the selector found no elements).

Comment: @Guffa: It's actually quite the opposite. A jQuery Object is not based on an array, it's an object which behaves "array-like" by adding `.length` and `.splice()`

Comment: Re-read the question. Summary: why array as result? And why selecting an identifier returns an array too? Now, re-read my answer :D

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer: I find no base for your summary in the question. Re-reading the question and reading your answer doesn't make me understand your earlier explanation.

Comment: Ok, no problem, others will do :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `$([selector])` is like a shortcut of `$.find([selector])` which is an element search.

That's anything executed with such `jQuery` functions may return one or more results, since you're searching rather than "selecting a result".