# Ember syntax to get element by ID not working

Tags: ember.js, getelementbyid

My HTML template is a basic:

```
<h1>Upload Photo</h1>

<form {{action "upload" on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="file" id="image"}}
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

I have this in my controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    upload() {
      console.log('Uploading photo from controller');
      var storageRef = this.get('firebaseApp').storage().ref();

      // var selectedFile = Ember.$('#image').files[0];
      var selectedFile = document.getElementById('image').files[0];

      console.log('selectedFile = ', selectedFile);

      // var photoRef = storageRef.child('ember-mascot.png');
    }
  }
});
```

If I use the normal javascript way:

```
var selectedFile = document.getElementById('image').files[0];
```

It works, I get a console log of the file.

However, if I use Ember's syntax of retrieving file:

```
var selectedFile = Ember.$('#image').files[0];
```

I get a javascript console error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

If I use:

```
var selectedFile = this.$('#image').files[0];
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.$ is not a function
```

According to this Stackoverflow answer:

[Getting element by ID in Ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742647/getting-element-by-id-in-ember)

`Ember.$()` or `this.$()` should work but it isn't for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$` is available only in component. if you create component everything will start to work.

```
ember g component upload-photo
```

In upload-photo.js,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    upload() {
      console.log('Uploading photo from controller');
      var storageRef = this.get('firebaseApp').storage().ref();

      // var selectedFile = Ember.$('#image').files[0];
      var selectedFile = document.getElementById('image').files[0];

      console.log('selectedFile = ', selectedFile);

      // var photoRef = storageRef.child('ember-mascot.png');
    }
  }
});
```

and in upload-photo.hbs,

```
<h1>Upload Photo</h1>

<form {{action "upload" on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="file" id="image"}}
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and include it in template like the below,

```
{{upload-photo }}
```

Comment: So in other words,  `Ember.$()` and `this.$()` can only be used inside components, otherwise, the only option that work in all cases is `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: `Ember.$` is equivalent to `$` but `this.$` is different, it will look inside the component scope. In your case issue is you are accesing it wrong. you need to access it like this `Ember.$('#image')[0].files[0]`

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know jQuery selector always return an array, even if the target is an id instead of a css class (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979891/does-jquery-always-return-array).

Comment: Me too, I tested in code using `console.log(Ember.$('#image'))`